# CoffeeScript: Setting default values for destructured arguments

Tags: javascript, function, coffeescript, underscore.js, lodash

In CoffeeScript, I can set default values for function parameters like so:

`func = (one = 'one') ->`

But how can I set default values when an object is passed like so:

`func = ({ one }) ->`

Doing the following *won't* work, for instance:

`func = ({ one: 'one' }) ->`

I am willing to use an external library like Lo-Dash, which provides [_.defaults](https://lodash.com/docs#defaults). So I can do the following:

```
func = (args) ->
  _.defaults args, { one: 'one' }
  { one } = args
```

But it's a little long for my taste. Particularly, I'd like to simplify it so that the `one` key/variable is mentioned only once. This makes it more useful for when I'm changing a function's parameters.

For instance, is there another method I can use, perhaps in yet another library (preferably one that already exists in LoDash though, of course) that would specifically destructure an object by using the object's keys as the new variable names?

Answer (score 0):

you have to assign it inside the function, unfortunately.

```
func =({one})->
  one ?= 1
  one

func(one: 2) #=> 2
func()  #=> 1
```

using lowdash, you could also do it on function call, of course

```
func _.defaults(ags, {one: 1})
```

depending on use case, that could be acceptable.

and then also you could use partial application

```
func = ({one})-> one

func1 = (fn, supplied)->
  (args)-> fn(_.defaults(args, supplied))

myFun = func1(func, one: 1)
myFun(foo: 'foo') #=> 1
myFun(one: 2) #=> 2
```

Comment: see here for closed request: https://github.com/jashkenas/coffeescript/issues/810